# Pass JQuery UI sortable results to PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I created a JQuery UI sortable list for a poll because I need users to sort the answers by order or preference (from 1 to 6).

I was able to get the responses order in a javascript object and I am now looking at the best way to pass this object to a PHP page that will count scores according to the response position in the list (eg: position 0 = 10pts, 1 = 15pts, etc.) and display the final score.

Is this the right way to retrieve the list order?
And is there a recommended way to post this to a php page? 
I was thinking of passing this object to an input hidden and post it with the form post.

Here is my code so far

```js
// Get number of questions
var nbQuestions = document.getElementsByClassName('question-group');

// Sortable list
$(function () {
  for ( var i = 0 ; i < nbQuestions.length ; i++ ) {
    $("#question"+(i+1)+"-responses, #question"+(i+1)+"-responses-out").sortable({
      placeholder: "list-group-item list-group-item-warning",
      connectWith: ".question"+(i+1),
      items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
    });
  }
});

// Get results in array 
function getResponses() {
  var Response = {
    init: function(question, responses) {
      this.question = question;
      this.responses = responses;
    }
  };
  // Array of all responses
  var allResponses = [];

  // For each question, get responses
  for ( var i = 0 ; i < nbQuestions.length ; i++ ) {
    var responses = $("#question"+(i+1)+"-responses").sortable("toArray"); // Reponses order
    var questionResponses = []; // Group question + responses
    questionResponses[i] = Object.create(Response);
    questionResponses[i].init("question"+(i+1), responses);
    allResponses.push(questionResponses[i]);
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(allResponses)); // for testing
  return JSON.stringify(allResponses);
}
```

```css
section ul:first-child {
margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <title>My page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <form id="form">
      <section id="question-group1">
        <div class="question-group">
          <ul id="question1-responses" class="responses question1 list-group">
            <li id="qr1" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q1-1</li>
            <li id="q1r2" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q1-2</li>
            <li id="q1r3" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q1-3</li>
            <li id="q1r4" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q1-4</li>
            <li id="q1r5" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q1-5</li>
            <li id="q1r6" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q1-6</li>
        </ul>

          <ul id="question1-responses-out" class="responses question1 list-group">
            <li class="ui-state-disabled list-group-item">Drag below unapplicable answers.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="question-group">
          <ul id="question2-responses" class="responses question2 list-group">
            <li id="q2r1" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q2-1</li>
            <li id="q2r2" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q2-2</li>
            <li id="q2r3" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q2-3</li>
            <li id="q2r4" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q2-4</li>
            <li id="q2r5" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q2-5</li>
            <li id="q2r6" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q2-6</li>
        </ul>

          <ul id="question2-responses-out" class="responses question2 list-group">
            <li class="ui-state-disabled list-group-item">Drag below unapplicable answers.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="question-group2">
        <div class="question-group">
          <ul id="question1-responses" class="responses question1 list-group">
            <li id="q3r1" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q3-1</li>
            <li id="q3r2" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q3-2</li>
            <li id="q3r3" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q3-3</li>
            <li id="q3r4" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q3-4</li>
            <li id="q3r5" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q3-5</li>
            <li id="q3r6" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q3-6</li>
        </ul>

          <ul id="question1-responses-out" class="responses question1 list-group">
            <li class="ui-state-disabled list-group-item">Drag below unapplicable answers.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="question-group">
          <ul id="question2-responses" class="responses question2 list-group">
            <li id="q4r1" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q4-1</li>
            <li id="q4r2" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q4-2</li>
            <li id="q4r3" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q4-3</li>
            <li id="q4r4" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q4-4</li>
            <li id="q4r5" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q4-5</li>
            <li id="q4r6" class="ui-state-default list-group-item">q4-6</li>
        </ul>

          <ul id="question2-responses-out" class="responses question2 list-group">
            <li class="ui-state-disabled list-group-item">Drag below unapplicable answers.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>

      <input type="submit" value="Send" id="getresponses">
    </form>
  </div>




  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is the result I get:

```
[{"question":"question1","responses":    ["q1r1","q1r2","q1r3","q1r4","q1r5","q1r6"]},{"question":"question2","responses":["q2r1","q2r2","q2r3","q2r4","q2r5","q2r6"]},{"question":"question3","responses":["q3r1","q3r2","q3r3","q3r4","q3r5","q3r6"]},{"question":"question4","responses":["q4r1","q4r2","q4r3","q4r4","q4r5","q4r6"]},{"question":"question5","responses":["q5r1","q5r2","q5r3","q5r4","q5r5","q5r6"]},{"question":"question6","responses":["q6r1","q6r2","q6r3","q6r4","q6r5","q6r6"]},{"question":"question7","responses":["q7r1","q7r2","q7r3","q7r4","q7r5","q7r6"]},{"question":"question8","responses":["q8r1","q8r2","q8r3","q8r4","q8r5","q8r6"]}]
```

Thanks

Comment: If you need to continue to another page, use the form. If not, use AJAX

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll do like this